# How can I find the implementation code for streaming data from Cloud Storage into BiqQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-shell

When I try to run the relevant code in Cloud Shell that would allow the streaming function to be deployed it claims that the source folder containing the streaming function itself does not exist.

The relevant buckets have already been created, it's the function itself which appears not to be there - would it be possible to install this separately maybe?

The original code followed by the error message is given below:

```
gcloud functions deploy streaming \
    --source=./functions/streaming --runtime=python37 \
    --stage-bucket=${FUNCTIONS_BUCKET} \
    --trigger-bucket=${FILES_SOURCE}


(gcloud.functions.deploy) argument '--source': Provided directory does not exist
```

Comment: Just to confirm, for the directory you are running this in the source path is accurate?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the error message, the path './functions/streaming' does not exist in your cloud shell. You have to pass the absolute path to the directory (in your cloud shell) where your python code is located. Please refer to the documentation below:

The source parameter can take 3 different locations:

> --source=SOURCE Location of source code to deploy. Location of the source can be one of the following three options:

- Source code in Google Cloud Storage (must be a .zip archive),
- Reference to source repository or,
- Local filesystem path (root directory of function source).

> Note that, depending on your runtime type, Cloud Functions will look
> for files with specific names for deployable functions. For Node.js,
> these filenames are index.js or function.js. For Python, this is
> main.py.